# How to import from Excel to selenium page one line at a time?

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium, openpyxl

I'm not a developer.

But I have to upload 10,000 products on Python to the site.

In Excel data, I want to import one row for each column to the selenium page.

I searched it for about a month and found it.

But that's not the way I want it to be.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSpgr.png)

Select the appropriate column for textarea and imgbtn.

The product is in the text area.

If there are values from img1 to 9, I want to bring them to imgbtn.

After importing, register the product with uploadbtn.

After 5 seconds, click again to register the product.

For textara and imgbtn, I would like to get the next line value from Excel.

How can you make a sentence like this?

I'm not good at English, so I'm getting help from a translator.

Please help me.T-T

```
firstbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div')
firstbtn.click()
time.sleep(3)

while True:
#product name upload code
    excel1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('c:/users/b/desktop/text.xlsx', data_only=True)
    sheet1 = excel1['text']

    max_row = sheet1.max_row
    max_column = sheet1.max_column

    for i in range(1, max_row+1):
        for j in range(1, max_column+1):
            cell_obj = sheet1.cell(row=i, column=j)
            pyperclip.copy(str(cell_obj.value))

            app = application.Application(
                backend='win32').connect(path="Chrome.exe")
        textarea = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/textarea[1]')
            textarea.send_keys(pyperclip.paste())
            keyboard.press_and_release('\t')
        keyboard.press_and_release('\n')
            time.sleep(2)

#image files upload code
    excel1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('c:/users/b/desktop/text.xlsx', data_only=True)
    sheet1 = excel1['text']

    max_row = sheet1.max_row
    max_column = sheet1.max_column

    for i in range(2, max_row+1):
        for j in range(2, max_column+1):
            cell_obj = sheet1.cell(row=i, column=j)
            pyperclip.copy(str(cell_obj.value))

            app = application.Application(
                backend='win32').connect(path="Chrome.exe")
        imgbtn= driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="file"]')
            imgbtn.send_keys("r'"+pyperclip.paste())
            keyboard.press_and_release('\t')
          keyboard.press_and_release('\n')
            time.sleep(2)

#upload button
    uploadbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[7]/div[1]/button').click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

When you execute the above code, the text area and imgbtn enter all the 10,000 values in Excel.T-T

Comment: Selenium will not work well for this.  See if the site has some kind of api for uploading thousands and thousands of products.  Many would have something as simple as uploading a mapped excel file.

Comment: Thank you, but the site I'm trying to upload is one that doesn't have API. I'll find another way.